# Magento overwrite checkout templates

Tags: magento

I need to overwrite `checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml` page. I tried some codes. But they did not work. My code is below;
in my layout file

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <reference name="onepage.review.info">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymoodule/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only checked in 1.6 and 1.9 Community, but it looks like the layout name of the info block is root, not onepage.review.info. Try this:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymoodule/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```